# [android]how can i create customize profile like meeting etc

Tags: android, profile

i m new in android i want to create application that gives option for create new profile (like meeting,outdore etc),manage profile(not location base it's manually)
plz help me

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, I'd suggest editing your question and making it a bit clearer. BTW: Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: Ah you want to make new themes (with wallpaper, widgets, etc)? I'm not even sure if the themes meeting and outdoor you mentioned are from Android or from HTC Sense

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to quickly switch between several profiles that change certain settings like Wifi On/Off, mutes all sounds, etc. right?
If that's what you want then your best bet would be to not re-invent the wheel and - depending on what phone you have - to install a custom ROM like CyanogenMOD which already features profile management. This would void your warranty though.

Otherwise, you could possibly achieve this with either an Xposed module (will most likely only work if you have a Nexus device, since it requires a pure "AOSP" version of Android and Root permissions) or the app "Tasker" which also requires Root access.